# how to change text order in linux?

Tags: linux

There are 3 updates in a textfile in linux, I just want to change the order of there like below, sed or awk alse have been tried but sounds complexed, maybe I can finished it in notepad, but any workarounds just using regular expression in linux ? Thanks.

orginal:

```
    UPDATE `test`.`t1`
    SET
    id=1 ,
    name='daiiy' ,
    sex=2 ,
    address='guangzhou' 
    WHERE
    id=1 ;



    UPDATE `test`.`t2`
    SET
    id=2 ,
    name='tom' ,
    sex=1 ,
    address='shanghai' 
    WHERE
    id=2 ;



    UPDATE `test`.`t3`
    SET
    id=3 ,
    name='liany' ,
    sex=2 ,
    address='beijing' 
    WHERE
    id=3 ;
```

how to change to:

```
    UPDATE `test`.`t3`
    SET
    id=3 ,
    name='liany' ,
    sex=2 ,
    address='beijing' 
    WHERE
    id=3 ;


    UPDATE `test`.`t2`
    SET
    id=2 ,
    name='tom' ,
    sex=1 ,
    address='shanghai' 
    WHERE
    id=2 ;

    UPDATE `test`.`t1`
    SET
    id=1 ,
    name='daiiy' ,
    sex=2 ,
    address='guangzhou' 
    WHERE
    id=1 ;
```

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: "I can finished it in notepad" -> What you want to do is EXTREMELY fast with any notepad (select lines, cut, paste elsewhere). If you are okay with using the notepad a little, then do everything with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to perl you can do the following..

```
    perl -0pe 's/(.*)^(.*)UPDATE(.*);(.*)UPDATE(.*);(.*)UPDATE(.*);(.*)/\2UPDATE\7;\n\n\2UPDATE\5;\n\n\2UPDATE\3;\n\n/s' input.txt
```

**Note**: this assumes that the indentation is the same for all three records.